# How eliminate rows in a dataframe with common values with other dataframe? Rstudio

Tags: dataframe, filter, dplyr, rstudio, row

I need to eliminate the rows in a dataframe that have at a column common values with the same column in a second dataframe

The columns the code have to take into account contain IDs of subjetcs, while the rest contain data refering to those subjects.

### Example of dataframes (Rstudio)

```
df1<-data.frame(ID=c(13, 16, 25, 36, 25, 17, 50, 63, 61, 34, 65, 17), AnyData=round(runif(12, 1, 5)))

df2<-data.frame(ID=c(89, 57, 13, 17, 18, 21, 51, 50, 72, 84), AnyData=round(runif(10, 1, 5)))
```

### I have tried two functions

```r
df1<- filter(df1, ID!=df2[ID])

df1<- df1[-c(which(df1[ID]==df2[ID]))]
```

### The result should be:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(16, 25, 36, 25, 63, 61, 34, 656), AnyData=(...)
```

AnyData depends on the values asigned with ruinf, so it will vary, but the value must be the same as in the original df1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an `anti_join()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  anti_join(df2, by = "ID")
```